# Setting up exchange 2019 with DKIM on Azure VM

Tags: windows, exchange, azure, dkim

I wanted to setup and configure my first exchange server on an Azure VM.

1. I presume I need to forward the MX records for my domain to the Azure VM?
2. Do I need to setup Active Directory on this new VM i.e. for each mailbox user or can it be done without AD?
3. DKIM - This tutorial and free plugin looks like it would work for email signing: https://www.emailarchitect.net/domainkeys/kb/dkim_exchange_2007_2010_2013.aspx#how-dkim-works

In summary, what are the minimum amount of things I need to do to setup my exchange server with DKIM?

Note - I will only have 20-30 email addresses with an extremely low inbound/outbound number of emails being sent/received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First - that DKIM plugin is not free. It is $299 a server.

You cannot run Exchange without Active Directory. It is not supported to run AD on the same server as Exchange 2019. Therefore you will need to have two VMs, one as a domain controller, and one as Exchange server. You will need a static IP address, which is what you can use for the MX records.

Or you could simply not bother and subscribe to Office365 - which is able to do DKIM signing for you. For 30 users, Azure will be an expensive option.

Comment: I have some free credit on Azure but I agree, 2 servers for 30 users is beyond madness. Would you know which Office 365 subscription I would need here?

Comment: Only you can decide on that. You might get away with the basic subscription E1 doesn't include the Office products, but you need to be aware of the limitations on what can be used for accessing Office365 soon. Business Premium therefore might be a good option.

Answer (score 0):

ou could buy Office 365 E1 Plan without Office application, or E3 plan with Office application.
Please refer to the official document for more details: 
Get the latest advanced features with Office 365
（you need to search this topic in google)